# Haskell, couldn't match type 'a' with 'Bool', code worked a couple days ago

Tags: haskell

```
all :: (a -> Bool) -> [Bool] -> Bool
all p = and . map p
```

I get error:

```
chapter7HigherOrder.hs:64:9: error:
• Couldn't match type ‘a’ with ‘Bool’
  ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by
    the type signature for:
      Main.all :: forall a. (a -> Bool) -> [Bool] -> Bool
    at chapter7HigherOrder.hs:63:8
  Expected type: [Bool] -> Bool
    Actual type: [a] -> Bool
• In the expression: and . map p
  In an equation for ‘all’: all p = and . map p
• Relevant bindings include
    p :: a -> Bool (bound at chapter7HigherOrder.hs:64:5)
    all :: (a -> Bool) -> [Bool] -> Bool
      (bound at chapter7HigherOrder.hs:64:1)
```

What is utterly strange is that this is from a text book, and it did work a couple of days ago. I am using VScode. Did some sort of update break this code?

Comment: This takes a list of boolean values and tries to apply a function `a -> Bool` to them. Did you mean to write `all :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Bool`? Then this should probably be closed as a typo, since it won't be particularly useful to future readers.

Comment: The book programming in Haskell by Hutton has it all :: (a -> Bool) -> [Bool] -> Bool

It takes a list of any number of items, and returns a list of Bools. then runs the and function. So [Bool] should be correct?

Comment: @TheProgramMAN123, `map p` returns the list of bools, and then `and` collapses them all into a single `Bool`.

Comment: @TheProgramMAN123 The list of `Bool`s is internal to `all`. `all` takes a list of elements of any type, *internally* (so *not* in the public API, *not* in the signature) *makes* (not returns!) a `[Bool]`, and then `and`s that list to get the publicly visible return value of type `Bool`. Presumably that's a typo in the book? [The real `all` has my type.](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/GHC-OldList.html#v:all) (Well, the *real*, real `all` is `all :: Foldable t => (a -> Bool) -> t a -> Bool`, but that's not important. It *used* to have my type, a long time ago.)

Comment: If the book has that type signature, then it is simply wrong - most likely a typo/misprint, sadly these are not uncommon. You are definitely mistaken if you believe this exact code, including the type signature, worked at any point in the past.

Comment: By parametricity, any function with signature `(a -> Bool) -> [Bool] -> Bool` must ignore its first argument, since it has no way to get an `a` to call it with.